# Помощь с foreach

Tags: php

Не могу понять что не так?, должна выводиться текущая тема.
Вместо этого выводиться весь список тем в переменную $t['code']

```
$site['theme'] = (!empty($site['theme']) && file_exists(BASE_PATH.'/folder/'.$site['theme'].'/cc.php') ? $site['theme'] : 'default');
include(BASE_PATH.'/folder/'.$site['theme'].'/cc.php');
    foreach(glob(BASE_PATH.'/folder/*/cc.php') as $tm){
        include($tm);
        echo $t['code'];/*Тут должна быть одна тема "one", вместо этого one,two....*/
        $selected = $site['theme'] == $t['code'] ? ' selected' : ''; 
        $set_def_theme .= '<option value="'.$t['code'].'"'.$selected.'>'.$t['name'].'</option>';
    }
```

Файл cc.php

```
$t['code']          = 'one';
$t['name']          = 'One';
```

Comment: Уже разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас при выводе просто слитно выводит? 
Попробуйте добавить перенос строки после вывода названия одной темы.

```
echo $t['code'] . '<br/>';
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, уже разобрался)